# Strange syntax issue with bind()

Tags: javascript

Why is it that in this example myFunction1 throws syntax error and myFunction2 works well? Shouldn't they be all the same?

```js
(function(){
  function MyClass(){
    this.val = "myVal";
    this.myFunction1();
    this.myFunction2();
  }

  MyClass.prototype.myFunction1 = function(){
    function otherFn() {
      console.log(this.val);
    }.bind(this);
    otherFn();
  }

  MyClass.prototype.myFunction2 = function(){
    var otherFn= function() {
      console.log(this.val);
    }.bind(this);
    otherFn();
  }

  var ins = new MyClass();
 })();
```

Comment: Both functions throws an syntax error currently, it just that the code stop executing after encountering the first error. function otherFn() {
      console.log(this.val);
  }.bind(this); is not syntaxically correct.

Comment: @StrandedKid: No, the `function2` one is fine.

Comment: check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/przemoo83/Lrxvwauw/

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Indeed my bad, read the code too fast. Though both function where declared inlined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference here is the difference between a *function declaration* and a *function expression*.

Your `function1` uses a *function declaration*:

```
MyClass.prototype.myFunction1 = function(){
  function otherFn() {
    console.log(this.val);
  }.bind(this);
  otherFn();
}
```

Function declarations are not expressions, and do not happen in the step-by-step execution of the code. They're done first, upon entry to the scope.

Since they're not expressions, they don't have a value, so there's nothing for `.bind` to work on.

Your second example uses a *function expression*:

```
MyClass.prototype.myFunction2 = function(){
  var otherFn= function() {
    console.log(this.val);
  }.bind(this);
  otherFn();
}
```

Since that's an *expression*, it's evaluated in the step-by-step execution of the code and has a resulting value, which `.bind` can operate on.

So **why** is the first a declaration? Purely because of how JavaScript's parsing rules are defined. If `function` is encountered when a statement is expected, it starts a function declaration. If `function` is encountered where an *expression* is expected, it starts a function expression.

In `function1`, `function` appears where a statement is expected, and thus is a declaration. In `function2`, though, it appears after the `var otherFn=`, and thus can only be an expression.

---

*(* "where a statement is expected" And in JavaScript, any expression [except a function expression] is allowed where a statement is expected, it's called the* ExpressionStatement. *So it ends up being "where a statement or non-function expression is expected. But the converse is not true, when an expression is expected, statements are not valid.)*

Comment: I need to digest this answer but I think I'm beginning to understand this:)

Comment: @przemoo83: :-) Basically, JavaScript has two different ways to define functions: Declarations and expressions. If you could write `if` where you write `function`, the `function` will start a declaration, not an expression. (There are also two different kinds of function expressions now as of ES2015's arrow functions, but that's not relevant here.)

Comment: Thanks for extensive feedback on this topic. It was worth being downvoted to learn something new:D

Answer (score 0):

```
function otherFn() {
    console.log(this.val);
}.bind(this);
```

is not correct.

It's just that when running first through your first function, the code breaks, then stop executing. So you never go through your 2nd function.

Try

```
var otherFn = function() {
    console.log(this.val);
}
otherFn.call(this);
```

instead.

Comment: What I actually wanted to know is why the first one is incorrect while the other is correct:)

Comment: @przemoo83 Ok, in this case T.J Crowder answer will fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to reason how javascript parses your code.otherFn in the Function1 is a parseTime Function so we cannot bind context at that time. Where as otherFn in Function2 is a runtime function so we can bind the context. So if you want to call the otherFn in the Function1 use the following syntax.

`otherFn.call(this)` in otherFn of Function1, which will bind the context at runtime.

Comment: No, both of them happen at runtime. They happen at *different times* at runtime, but it's runtime in both cases.